# Where does the triggers reside in MVC?

Tags: java, mysql

I am in confusion to identify the role of triggers in MVC pattern, some one is saying that triggers operates with database and it comes under model part and some one saying that triggers controlls the data to be inserted or updated to the database and comes to controller part of MVC. Please tell me the role of triggers in MVC pattern.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no single answer to your question. It depends from which angle you look at the problem. This is a matter of opinion only.

Answer (score 1):

When a certain event happens like CRUD operation for example, an event dispatcher and event handler is called which does some action after the CRUD operation. this is the role of triggers

if you are dealing with only the database and triggers are CRUD operation, then the triggers belong to the model layer, the controller acts only as a connection between the view and the model

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are always resides in controller.

Models: Contains your old object which only get and set data to use anywhere.
Models are always make to store some data data in plain old object.

While controller which controls on flow, so **triggers are also top-level standard object that controls over models** to fire action on any other  standard or custom objects.

For more info please visit:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm

or

http://amitsalesforce.blogspot.in/2015/04/model-view-controller-mvc-paradigm.html

Comment: just curious,  if triggers are objects that control models, then how do you justify that it belongs to the controller? just  because they operate on the same model layer does not mean they are the same, its either on its own layer or a part of model layer